# Shall we say/write "involved in" or "with" a recruitment process?

Tags: prepositions

I  need to add the following sentence in my resumé, as a direct consequence from recently having been involved by my HR manager in the recruitment processes whenever an applicant is coming for an interview:

> "On behalf of the HR Department, direct involvement **in/with**(?) the
>   recruitment processes with specific regard to candidates’ language
>   assessments in English by testing their skills in fluency and
>   writing".

Which preposition is the most appropriate?

Comment: I edited your question for ease of reading (less cluter) , you can chose to revert to the original.

Comment: As far as I can tell, neither "in" nor "with" result in a complete grammatical sentence. Consider using a simpler sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working on a resume, you should use short, bulleted sentences or phrases. Something like these two bullets would be more effective at conveying your experience:

> Recruited new candidates in the HR Department.
>
> Assessed candidates' English fluency and writing skills using tests.

You can be more specific here on the second bullet. Why type of tests? How were they administered? Were they designed by you?